# Does a twitter account ID can be equals to a tweet ID?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Or do I have to build myself a unique identifier ?
(I use twitter4j API to retrieve tweets from my friends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they can. However the ID of a tweet is very often far more greater than a user ID (big `long` number vs. an `ìnt` < 1,000,000,000). They might be equals for very old tweets but definitely not for recent ones (for example Twitter hasn't got [271,674,757,445,996,545](https://twitter.com/MozillaZineFr/status/271674757445996545) users to make a confusion yet).